# Can you build with the iOS6 SDK but keep letter-boxing on the iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, ios6

Apps built using the iOS5 SDK result in a window that fits the 3.5" screens of the iPhone 4S and lower. If the same app is run on the iPhone 5 with the 4" display, it gets letter-boxed. Once one upgrades to the iOS6 SDK, it seems that the same app will get a full-screen window on an iPhone 5. Is there a way to stick with the iOS6 SDK but force the app to use the 3.5" screen resolution only (i.e. put the letter-boxing back)?

p.s. In my situation this won't be permanent but I want to focus on the 3.5" app layout until such time that I'm ready to work on making the app reflow properly on the larger screen.

Update: Also wanted to point out that I know Apple is disallowing apps that don't support 4" screens in the App Store soon. I'm just concerned about AdHoc deployment for testing right now.

Comment: it should be possible... I think you have to remove the iphone 5 loading screen. But you have to hurry .. apple requires iphone5 and retina support for all uploads starting in may.

Comment: btw it should not update apps created with previous xcode versions automaticly. I updated 2 apps for a customer using the latest xcode and they are still iphone 4 only.

Comment: Thanks @Bastian, you're right that it wouldn't update the app to use the full screen when upgrading the project. I was talking hypothetically and implied an actual upgrade of the project would do that. In my case I'm starting out with iOS6. On your suggestion to remove the iPhone 5 loading screen, that was it! I renamed Default-568@2x.png and did a clean and build and now I get letter-boxing. If you want to create an answer below with that info I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will disable the iphone5 screen size for your app when you remove the Default-568@2x.png loading screen.

Comment: Be aware that starting May 1, Apple will reject apps that don’t support the taller iPhone. \[[source](https://developer.apple.com/news/)]

Comment: yeah ... that was already mentioned in the comments of this question

Answer (score 0):

May 1 is coming soon , just forget this way. adjust your layout for your iPhone5's UI.